# Existe "Require once" em Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz uma classe em JS (Modelo ES6), ta funcionando beleza, mas como eu faço pra colocar ela num arquivo externo e dar, um `Require Once` como no PHP? Tem como fazer isso? Valeu ;)

Answer (score 0):

Isso depende do seu ambiente, se você for utilizar usando jQuery no webbrowser (para um site, por exemplo), você pode dar uma olhada nos plugins como [browserify](http://browserify.org/) que fazem mais ou menos o modelo do `require` do NodeJS.

Se você estiver utilizando o ambiente do Node, então basta usar o próprio `require`, mas não acredito que haja um `require_once`, até porque os objetos são armazenados em variáveis, eles não são incorporados ao ambiente.